# How to catch invalid action types in redux

Tags: redux

I want to be notified if I forget to handle an action type in my reducers. I could make a reducer with a whole list of action types to check against, but that doesn't stop me from forgetting to modify reducers in the first place.

Edit: I am using multiple reducers with combineReducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be at least one unhandled action type: INIT. In dev mode, redux will dispatch an action with a **random** type and also outside of dev mode, you should not act on that action (that is the reason it's random in dev mode).

Really: it is okay to dispatch actions that are not handled by reducers (yet). Actions should describe what is going on in your application, not necessarily be thought of "calling a change in state".

But adding to that: If you write [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), it is also pretty uncommon that this happens by accident. You might want to look into modern redux with redux toolkit - the last link is a good start and the [official redux essentials tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) would be a good place to follow up on modern redux patterns.
Also take a look at the [redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's is possible. You can throw an error if no action type is matched.

Use this at the end of the reducer function. (*but Don't set default type*)

```
throw new Error("Action not matched");
```

Comment: This won't work for using multiple reducers with combineReducers because a single reducer will throw that error even if another reducer handles that action.